# HTML Mailto: works with Gmail but not Yahoo

Tags: html, email, gmail, yahoo, mailto

So I have a simple html e-mail I am testing on outlook, gmail & yahoo.

The HTML email contains two links that open a pre-made reply, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Accept or Reject</title>
</head> 
    <body>

        <a href="mailto:EMAIL?subject=I%20Accept&body=I%20would%20like%20to%0D%0AAccept">
        Accept
        </a>

    &nbsp

        <a href="mailto:EMAIL?subject=I%20Reject&body=I%20would%20like%20to%0D%0AReject">
        Reject
        </a>

    </body>
```

When I click accept or reject from within gmail it will reply using Gmail, however when I use Yahoo or outlook.com it opens outlook on the desktop.

How do i force it to reply using the web service it was opened with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [post](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100714073520AATnaJa) i think it is use full for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, trying to do it without having to change the default client tho, might not be possible.